# How do I programmatically compare files at two revisions in git?

Tags: git, git-plumbing

I want to compare two versions of a file (which exist at different paths) at different commits in git.  I don't want the diff, I simply want to know if the contents and modes are the same.  The documentation for diff-files doesn't indicate any meaning for return values.  I don't see something similar to cmp(1) in git.  Is there another plumbing tool to do this or does diff-files have return values that express this?

Comment: I suppose if the files are the same they should be the same blob.  Does the blob hash include the mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`git ls-tree <commit> -- <path>` outputs

> `<mode> SP <type> SP <object> TAB <file>`

`<mode>` is the file mode. `<object>` is the sha1  that indicates the content.

Compare the modes and objects.

`<object>` here can be named in another way

> `<commit>:<path>`

So `git rev-parse <commit>:<path>` can output the sha1 of the blob or the tree. Comparing the two sha1, we can see if the contents are the same or not.

Answer (score 3):

`git diff --exit-code <commit> <commit>` I believe you looking for.
Its almost down the bottom in the docs  https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff

Or

`git diff --quiet  <commit> <commit>` If your purely interested in the exit code and nothing more (no console output)